# List of number as rows Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to build a Employee management system. The system is having server code in JAVA and Database Oracle. from Java side I am passing three elements **List Of Date, List of Location and List of Shift**.

Now I have 1 table which has all entries for Shifts which are applicable to particular locations.

For Example If Location 1 has two shift 1 , 2 and Location 2 has two shift 1, 3 then table will look like this.

```
Location | Shift
       1 | 1
       1 | 2
       2 | 1
       2 | 3
```

Now what I want is, When I pass Date List (01-01-2017, 01-02-2017) from Java my query should return table structure should look like below.

```
 Date       | Location | Shift
 01-01-2017 |       1 | 1
 01-01-2017 |       1 | 2
 01-01-2017 |       2 | 1
 01-01-2017 |       2 | 3
 01-02-2017 |       1 | 1
 01-02-2017 |       1 | 2
 01-02-2017 |       2 | 1
 01-02-2017 |       2 | 3
```

Please suggest query.

Please note that **Date** field is not part of any table and List size can vary based on call.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Date is a column in the first table?

Comment: How are you passing your lists from Java to Oracle? Are you actually just passing two values, a start and end date; or could there be more than two? What data types are the vales being passed, and the table columns?

Comment: Date List size is dynamic and Date is not part of any table

Comment: One part of the problem (even if you didn't need to relate to locations and shifts in any way) is to simply convert your Java list of dates into an Oracle table of dates (in a single column). Once you do that, you need a Cartesian or "cross" join between the date table and the location/shift table.

Answer (score 0):

Following query should work I guess:

```
SELECT DATESTABLE.DATES,LOCATIONS, SHIFTS
FROM LOCATIONSTABLE
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT '01-01-2017'
UNION ALL
SELECT '01-02-2017'
) DATESTABLE
ON 1 = 1;
```

You can use order by to order accordingly.

Comment: `... inner join ...  on 1 = 1` is better written as  `... cross join ...` - that way it is obvious that the cross join is intentional, rather than some mistake where someone forgot to add the actual join conditions.